# Browser can access web service, but my C# app gets "Could not establish trust relationship"

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, ssl

I have a C# console app on a Windows Server 2003 machine that sends data (over SSL) to a web service hosted on a Windows Server 2003 R2 machine.  I have the entire certificate chain installed on both the Current User and Local Computer certificate stores in MMC (Microsoft Management Console).

I can hit the web service (.asmx page) in IE and Firefox just fine.  I'm assuming because it uses the Current User certificate store.  However, my C# app returns the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with
>   authority 'www.samplewebservice.com'. ---> System.Net.WebException:
>   The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

It's almost like the certificate isn't stored in the right "account" or "container" in MMC.  I browsed through the various service accounts and they all seem to have the cert.  I know .NET runs under the "NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" account but "Network Service" isn't listed under the Service Accounts in MMC.  I checked the following service accounts and they all had the correct certificates (I never copied them so I'm assuming it's because they're in the Local Computer account):

- Computer Browser
- Network Connections
- Network Manager

I'm completely stumped.  It's like .NET doesn't have access to the certificates.  I wish I could use a keystore similar to Java.  Has anyone ever came across this?

Comment: Are you using the exact same host (www.samplewebservice.com) in your manual IE/Firefox requests as in the C# request?

Comment: Are the C# requests being made from an application or service?

Comment: You've said user and local, but are they in the trusted certificate store?

Comment: As jglouie mentioned, ensure that the domain name in your client endpoint address matches with the domain name that the cert was issued to.

Comment: It probably has no bearing on this problem, but it looks like you're using a WCF client against an ASMX service. Any particular reason?

Comment: jglouie's question is pertinent: whose user account is the C# app running under? Your own, i.e. the same account as the browser? If so, then it'll be using the same certificate store as the browser. I'm not sure why you're checking that _service accounts_ have access to the certificate chain, when it's a _console app_ (unlikely to be run by a service account) that needs to find it.

Comment: @jglouie, no, I just put that in there as a sample.  The actual web service isn't available online to the public. The request is being made from a C# Windows Console Application to a C# web service (traditional SOAP-based web service, not WCF).

Comment: @Matthew Abbott, they're in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities (root cert) and the Intermediate Certification Authorities (two intermediate certs) folders in MMC.

Comment: @RoccoC5, yes, the "Issued to" value and the domain match up.

Comment: @shambulator, the request is being made from a C# Windows Console Application to a C# web service (traditional SOAP-based web service, not WCF).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I got around by deleting the certificates, reinstalling them and restarting both PC and IIS. Also make sure your certificatess haven't expired and are trusted in the machine's store.

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere early in your processing pipeline:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a,b,c,d) => true;
```

This is to ensure that all certificates are accepted.

Of course as John points out, such general callback could possibly be dangerous so please fine tune it so that on one hand it solves your issue and on the other hand it doesn't introduce any security issues.

I hope John is satisfied now. I should have been more talkative, and so should he :)

Comment: The asking person with a 1200+ rating is probably well aware of possible consequences. And a bare "sounds dangerous" sounds impolite. It doesn't add much to the topic.

Comment: Nor does ignoring the problem and just throwing away certificate validation :P

Comment: "Sounds dangerous" would be a hint for the person whom I downvoted that he should address the danger in the answer.

Comment: A word is enough to the wise.

Comment: While this may be an answer in some case (eg. "I don't have or care about a valid certificate, or otherwise wish to process the handshake differently") this is does not address the current question.

Comment: @user2864740: not only it does, not only you don't say what does in your opinion but also this question is almost 4 years old. You would contribute to community by providing actual answers that are valid in your opinion. Instead, you merely repeated what John said back then. I wish to understand what value your comment introduces to anyone reading this.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Something worth saying once is worth repeating - especially when it has been so flippantly thrown off. Policing up after answers is a form of contribution, regardless of how old the question is. (Had I not run into the question trying to solve my own question I would have never encountered this answer.)